# Chi distribution and sample variance

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, sampling

> Suppose that the height (in cm) of randomly selected male is
>   distributed according to normal distribution with parameters $\mu  = 175$ and $\sigma  = 5$. We pick a simple random sample of size $101$
>   from population of males. What is the value such that the probability,
>   that the sample variance is larger than this value, is $0.05$?

**Solution attempt:**

For a normal population, the quantity $${{(n-1)s^2} \over{\sigma^2} }$$ is known to have a chi-squared distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

So then 
$$P[{s^2} > X] = P\left[ {\frac{{(101 - 1){s^2}}}{{{5^2}}} > X} \right] = P\left[ {\chi^2_{(100)}> X} \right] = 0.05$$

Using $R$ command: `qchisq(p = 0.05, df = 100, lower.tail = FALSE)` i found that $$X \approx 124.3421$$

Have i solved this problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the equation $$P[s^2>X]=P\left[\frac{(101-1)s^2}{5^2}>X\right]$$ You need to multiply both sides of the inequality by $\frac{101-1}{5^2}$, not just the left side.